# Execute command that was displayed on the screen as a message

Tags: bash, shell

A message is displayed many times on the screen after entering certain command. I need to retype the entire suggested command or copy and paste it. Is there a shortcut to do the same using the terminal.

For e.g.

```
$ vagrant up
```

The message was:

```
Message: Please install the vagrant-vbguest plugin by 
running `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`
```

I wish to run the command `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`.

Comment: The shortcut would be just copy-pasting `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` from the command output :) . As far as I can see, tweaking the system to execute the message displayed in command might create whole other problems.

Comment: @Sree don't wish to tweak the system to execute message displayed. Here's the step I wish to do
1) Run a regex on last displayed output to find command.
2) Execute it.

Answer (score 1):

If the install command is quoted by backticks, and the line is split by newline as posted.

An example:

```
msg='Message: Please install the vagrant-vbguest plugin by\nrunning `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`'


status=$( vagrant up )
cmd=$( echo "$status" | grep -o "by\nrunning \`[a-z \-]*" | cut -d"\`" -f 2 )
```

OR

```
cmd=$( echo "$msg" | cut -d"\`" -f 2 )
```

And then:

```
# if cmd is not empty
if [[ -n "$cmd" ]]; then
    sudo "$cmd"
fi
```

Also if that message is printed out on STDERR then replace with:

```
status=$( vagrant up 2>&1 )
```

Comment: that makes it even harder :)

Comment: @SudipKafle Why not use the: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html ... `grep -o` returns only what it finds.  The basic idea is to use `cut` to split the string and store it in a variable. I updated my answer.